# Lightweight home bookkeeping / spending accounting service

Tags: finance

Please, recommend a good service to account daily spendings.

It should be very easy to add spendings on the move -- via a native Android app or a responsive webapp.

It would be great if this service is able to draw nice graphs of spending trends by month and/or spending category.

Not needed: tax calculation and generation of any documents, integration with credit cards or bank accounts, any USA-specific features.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Toshl](https://toshl.com/) in Europe. It is a webapp application where you can add your income and your spending in categories etc. There is an android and an iOS application. Very funny visualizations, bill reminders and my favotire. The option to export your stats in a pdf or excel file.

If you are in USA, I have found a better one. I haven't used [Mint](https://www.mint.com/), but reviews and screenshots are amazing.

Answer (score 2):

Update 1/2016: The new version of YNAB is now a web app.  I haven't tried it (I'm sticking with the no-longer-promoted desktop app for now), so I can't wholeheartedly recommend it at this time.

---

Original review 2/2014:

I've tried several different software and web app solutions over the years to track my spending, and my favorite (and the one I am currently using) is called [You Need A Budget](http://www.youneedabudget.com/) (YNAB).

YNAB is a desktop application in which you draw up a monthly budget for your household spending.  You put in your income as it comes in (assigning it to both an account and a budget category) and then you enter your spending as it happens, telling YNAB which account you spent the money from and which category the transaction belongs to.  YNAB keeps track of how much money you have in each category, so you know instantly how much money you have left in your budget for each category.

Because it is not a web app, you don't have to worry about the company mining your data for advertising purposes or handing it over to anyone.  However, you can install YNAB on as many computers as you need, and are able to use native iOS or Android apps.  The way this is done is though Dropbox: Each YNAB installation syncs itself over Dropbox.  In my experience, this works flawlessly.

One of the downsides of YNAB is that it does not interface with your bank to download transaction automatically.  However, since I've had so many problems with these interfaces in the past with other solutions, I don't miss that feature.  You are able to download transactions from your bank and import them into YNAB, if you like.

Your requirements:

- Yes, it is easy to add spending transactions via native Android or iOS apps.
- Yes, it does draw graphical reports of spending by month and by spending category.

It is not a web app, but since it does allow multiple installations, synced via Dropbox, in my opinion it has all of the advantages of web apps without the drawbacks.

Comment: Is this a lightweight solution?

Comment: @leventov How do you define lightweight?

Comment: I don't have Dropbox (and any other synchronizing software) on 3 of 4 of target "computers" (PCs and phones). How simple to make YNAB working in this case?

Comment: @leventov You can use YNAB without Dropbox, it just won't sync with your other PCs and phones.  Installing Dropbox on a PC is easy and free.  (The YNAB files are not that big, so the free Dropbox account is enough.)  You don't need to install Dropbox on the phones; the mobile apps interface with the Dropbox servers directly.