# IPhone software that would allow me to track expenses with my wife

Tags: iphone-app, finance

I'm looking for recommendations for an app that my wife and me can both use to both track our household expenses.  Ideally it'd allow you to create a budget with different types of expense which you can then both track as you spend on both your phones.  I actually wrote an app to do this a while ago for PC which syncs over DropBox but I'm looking for an IPhone solution without having to write one myself.

I don't mind spending some money on the app if it's good although wouldn't mind an app that lets you try before you buy to see if it's any good. Ideally I want an app that let's both us input expenses and tracks who's entering them etc so we can work on the same budget. Syncing to the desktop would be neat (or a web interface) but the critical thing is that we can use our phones to input the tracking data since they're always with us.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, looks like this might do what I need: https://goodbudget.com/ it allows a shared iphone budget.  Not sure if anyone has tried it.

Comment: Related: [Lightweight home bookkeeping / spending accounting service](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/938/83)